# Umbraco - Dynamic Pages

Tags: umbraco

I was hoping someone might be able to give me some help with what I am planning to do...

I want to create a dynamic "City.aspx" page that accepts a url parameter and dynamically generates a page based on that particular city.

For example, if someone called "City.aspx?city=london" then it would build a page with custom content relating to London and if someone called the page "City.aspx?city=manchester" it would build the page with content relating to Manchester.

I have looked into building the sitemap and UrlRewriting and am pretty sure i can redirect to this new page with a parameter but have no idea what I need to do next.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

TaxiRoute

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you create url's like /city/london/1234 where the last part is the ID of your document.
By using the built-in UrlRewrite function in Umbraco, you can make the url be internally rewritten to /city.aspx?name=london&id=1234
In the /config/Urlewriting.config you can add rewrite rules.
For the above you need something like this:

```
 <add name="city_rewrite"
       virtualUrl="^~/city/(.*)/(.*)"
       rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
       destinationUrl="~/city.aspx?name=$1&amp;cityid=$2"
       ignoreCase="true" />
```

Once you have this sorted out, you can use the following code in your code-behind off the City.aspx Macro to get the corresponding Document.

```
    // get the city Document Id from the querystring
    string cityID = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["cityid"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cityId))
    {
      // get the cityNode
      Node cityNode = new Node(cityId);
      // do whatever you want with this node, like display it's data
    }
```

This is a .NET Macro, but of course you can do the same with XSLT or Razor-code.

Comment: Wouldn't the city and Id be redundant? Certainly easier to code in the macro though.

Comment: City and ID are indeed redundant, but for SEO the name of the city is better and if you want to get the Node from Umbraco, it is easier to use the Node ID because the ID is unique, the node name doesn't have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the information outside of standard Umbraco content that is dynamic for each city, then simply write a macro or macros (or partial views?) to get the dynamic data via that "city" get parameter. Then you can use UrlRewriting to make URLs look like standard web pages (/city/london.aspx).  UrlRewriting will make that URL appear to the server as though it was this: /city.aspx?city=london. (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/packaging/package-actions/community-made-package-actions/add-an-url-rewrite-rule)

In your macros you can either pass the "city" get parameter to the macro(s) as a macro parameter via bracket syntax (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax). Or your can just get the city parameter via request variables (razor) or Umbraco.library (XSLT).