# How to construct URL in pointing to pages in umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

How do I construct URL in umbraco? So I have a list of Firms, now when I click on a firm name, I want it to show firm's profile.

Firms list and Firm's profile are two separate user controls and have two Umbraco pages(nodes) embedding the Usercontrol.

So I need dev.xxx.com/322.aspx?firmId=242 but I woulnt know the page name as in 322.apsx and I dont want to hardcode it.

Any ideas?

Chirdeep

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Umbraco built-in UrlRewrite module to create "virtual" pages for your page with firms list and your page with firm's profile.
[See my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414680/umbraco-dynamic-pages/14426489#14426489) for a similar example